# Ubuntu 14.04 disappeared

Tags: dual-boot

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit .iso from official Ubuntu site. While installing it from a bootable USB drive I selected to replace Windows 8. The installer removed all my partitions and replaced it with an Ubuntu one.

I then installed Windows 8 by making a separate partition out of the Ubuntu space. I did not get any option to boot Ubuntu.

Why can't I boot Ubuntu and how do I fix this? And is there any way to get back my files(a whole lot collection of Programmes, Movies, Games and Music?

Comment: Where were these files (Programmes, Movies, Games and Music) before you reinstalled Windows? If they were in the old Windows 8 partition, they're likely toast now.

Answer (score 1):

You installed Ubuntu first and then windows operating system. So, Boot-loader of Ubuntu is no longer exist in mbr.

Now You have to recover Ubuntu boot-loader. To do that visit instruction given on Ubuntu help: [Recover Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)